# (Almost) Same code produces unchecked assignment in one place and does not in the other

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rest-assured

I am parsing a RestAssured call in Java which returns a list of objects. If I am using this code, Idea produces the unchecked assignment warning:

```
List<SpaceInventoryDTO> availableInventories = ListParserHelper.getList(response, SpaceInventoryDTO.class);


public class ListParserHelper {
  public static <T> List getList(Response response, Class<T> cls) {
    return response.jsonPath().getList(".", cls);
  }
```

However, if I put the code from the helper into the class itself, the warning is no longer produced:

```
List<SpaceInventoryDTO> availableInventories = response.jsonPath().getList(".", SpaceInventoryDTO.class);
```

I am interested in underlying logic here, what am I missing?

Comment: The method returns a **raw** `List`. Have you tried declaring `List<T>` as the return type?

Comment: Thanks Ernest, I feel rather silly now for not noticing it! Care to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method's return type is the raw `List` type, whereas the `getList` method returns a proper generic type (I presume). You need to give your return type a concrete type argument to get rid of the warning:

```
public static <T> List<T> getList(Response response, Class<T> cls)
```